# Azure Automation task is billable? if yes how pricing will happen? Please suggest

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to turn off my Azure VM's on saturday & sunday to save the cost of usage.
for that i am planning to use the configuration of VM there is automation option inside that tasks have used for templates to create where it shows this task is billable, may i know how the pricing will happen if it is billable for the task?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, Azure automations tasks are billable. It depends on jobs run time minutes used in month
2. When you create automation account in azure you will get 500 minutes of free job run time ,if you use more than 500 minutes you will pay extra minutes
3. If you want to stop the virtual machines in weekends you can create a scheduled runbooks using Azure powershell or Azure CLI, you can create schedule the runbooks using azure portal
4. If you need more details about the pricing for Azure Automation and how costs are calculated.

You can visit the Microsoft link provided on the pricing page for Azure Automation.
[Pricing Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/automation/)